# How is restic outputting data to the screen but not to stdout or stderr?

Tags: python, subprocess, stdout, stderr, flush

#### Updating line

I have a question about where the output of a certain command is going. I'm using `restic` as an example of a command that behaves this way. It's the last line of the command that's of interest to me, because it updates while the restore process is working.

For context, restic's a back-up utility; the command below is restoring the contents of `my-repo` from a backup stored on `example.com` back to my local machine.

```
$ restic restore latest --repo sftp:matt@example.com:my-repo --target . --verbose
repository ae412afe opened (version 1)
restoring <Snapshot dff2f51a> to /Users/matt
[0:11] 0.02%  192 files 37.687 MiB, total 39644 files 171.389 GiB
```

The last line updates over time until it reaches 100%, e.g.

```
[12:31] 1.22%  2989 files 2.087 GiB, total 39644 files 171.389 GiB
```

---

### Execute from python

I want to run the restore command from a Python script (using `subprocess.Popen`) and want the script to print out the updating line but haven't been able to get that working.

I suspected it could be that the updating line was being output to stderr instead of stdout. So I repeated the restore command and redirected the stdout and stderr to files, as below:

```
restic restore lat...rbose > out.log 2> err.log
```

`err.log` remains empty, and `out.log` only contains the `restoring <Snapshot dff2f51a> to /Users/matt` line, nothing else.

---

### Python snippet

Here's the snippet of my code calling Popen:

```
backup_command = [
    # fmt: off
    "restic",
    "--repo", repo_name,
    "backup",
    "--verbose",
    "--exclude", "node_modules",
    "--exclude", "whatever",
    # fmt: on
]
backup_process = subprocess.Popen(backup_command, env=env_vars)
backup_process.wait()
```

In reference to jurez's answer below, I'm not passing `stdin` or `stderr`, but having looked at the source for Popen, they default to `None`, as per jurez's suggestion.

---

### Questions

I have a couple of questions.

- Why isn't the `repository ae412afe opened (version 1)` line in either of my output files?
- Where is the `[0:11] 0.02%  192 fil...` line going? And how can I show it?

Comment: From the `restic` documentation: "When running from a non-interactive console progress reporting is disabled by default to not fill your logs."  Apparently you can override this by providing a `RESTIC_PROGRESS_FPS` environment variable.

Comment: Thank you @jasonharper, that's done it! I'll read the docs myself next time ‍♂️ Can you post that as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [restic documentation](https://restic.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual_rest.html):

> **When running from a non-interactive console progress reporting is disabled by default to not fill your logs.** For interactive and non-interactive consoles the environment variable `RESTIC_PROGRESS_FPS` can be used to control the frequency of progress reporting. Use for example 0.016666 to only update the progress once per minute.

My use of `Popen` creates a non-interactive shell, resulting in no progress reporting output. Setting the value works as advertised. I find it easier to think of as "seconds between each update" rathen that "frames per second" so use `1 / INTERVAL_IN_SECONDS` to set the FPS.

*Credit to [jasonharper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76991513/how-is-restic-outputting-data-to-the-screen-but-not-to-stdout-or-stderr?noredirect=1#comment135774357_76991513) for looking up the docs, thanks!*

Answer (score 0):

From the [Popen documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html):

> stdin, stdout and stderr specify the executed program’s standard input, standard output and standard error file handles, respectively. Valid values are PIPE, DEVNULL, an existing file descriptor (a positive integer), an existing file object with a valid file descriptor, and None. PIPE indicates that a new pipe to the child should be created. DEVNULL indicates that the special file os.devnull will be used. With the default settings of None, no redirection will occur; the child’s file handles will be inherited from the parent. Additionally, stderr can be STDOUT, which indicates that the stderr data from the applications should be captured into the same file handle as for stdout.

This means that if you use `stdin=None` and `stderr=None` in `Popen` constructor, the subprocess will inherit the `STDIN` and `STDERR` file descriptors from Python. In other words, any output that program will send to those streams will appear as Python's own standard output / standard error.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I'm afraid it's not helped. I should have posted a snippet of my python app, I'm already using `stidin=None` and `stderr=None`